# Print all lines between line containing a string and first blank line, starting with the line containing that string

Tags: bash, awk

I've tried awk:

```
awk -v RS="zuzu_mumu" '{print RS $0}' input_file > output_file
```

The obtained file is the exact input_file but now the first line in file is `zuzu_mumu`.
How could be corrected my command?

After solved this, I've found the same string/patern in another arrangement; so I need to save all those records that match too, in an output file, following this rule:

- if pattern match on a line, then look at previous lines and print the first line that follows an empty line, and print also the pattern match line and an empty line.

record 1

record 2

This is record 3 first line
info 1
info 2
This is one matched zuzu_mumu line
info 3
info 4
info 5

record 4

record 5

...

This is record n-1 first line
info a
This is one matched zuzu_mumu line
info b
info c

record n

...

I should obtain:

This is record 3 first line
This is one matched zuzu_mumu line

This is record n-1 first line
This is one matched zuzu_mumu line

Comment: consider reviewing [how do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update the question accordingly; in particular, provide sample input, the code you've tried, the (wrong) output generated by your code and the (correct) desired output

Comment: `sed -n '/pattern/,/^$/p' file.txt | sed '$d'`
or `awk '/pattern/{flag=1}/^$/{flag=0}flag' file.txt`

Comment: @ufopilot please don't post answers as comments as then they don't get upvoted/downvoted/commented on as appropriate.

Comment: `RS="zuzu_mumu"` sets the end-of-line *Record Separator* (`RS`) to the string value `"zuzu_mumu"`, so that will get printed with EVERY line written to the file....

Comment: Thank you very much, @ufopilot ! the awk worked perfect! that string is present in many lines/records, and the command indicated by you outputs all matches - exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

> Print all lines between line containing a string and first blank line,
> starting with the line containing that string

I would use GNU `AWK` for this task. Let `file.txt` content be

```
Able
Baker
Charlie

Dog
Easy
Fox
```

then

```
awk 'index($0,"aker"){p=1}p{if(/^$/){exit};print}' file.txt
```

output

```
Baker
Charlie
```

Explanation: use [`index` String function](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) which gives either position of `aker` in whole line (`$0`) or `0` and treat this as condition, so this is used like *is `aker` inside line?* Note that using `index` rather than regular expression means we do not have to care about characters with special meaning, like for example `.`. If it does set `p` value to `1`. If `p` then if it is empty line (it matches start of line followed by end of line) terminate processing (`exit`); `print` whole line as is.

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thank you very much, @Daweo ! That only outputs the first matching record and exits; there are many records that match the patern - I wanted all of them in a file.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to match the same line again, you can record all lines in an array and print the valid lines in the END block.

```
awk '
f && /zuzu_mumu/ {              # If already found and found again
  delete ary; entries=1; next;  # Delete the array, reset entries and go to the next record
}
f || /zuzu_mumu/ {              # If already found or match the word or interest
  if(/^[[:blank:]]*$/){exit}    # If only spaces, exit
  f=1                           # Mark as found
  ary[entries++]=$0             # Add the current line to the array and increment the entry number
}
END {                             
  for (j=1; j<entries; j++)     # Loop and print the array values
      print ary[j]
}
' file
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @The fourth bird ! That only outputs the first matching record and exits; there are many records that match the patern - I wanted all of them in a file. Even if I got rid of the part "if already found and found again", still returns just one record. But, very nice to have this to practice a cycle! Much help!

Comment: @maria79 That is because your question states `between line containing a string and first blank line,`